# LXML parsing for an HTML file

Tags: python, lxml

I wrote this code to parse an HTML file which is basically a report generated by a software. This file is 40+ MB in size. The code is 100% perfect. The only problem that I am facing is the parsing process is extremely slow. It took nearly 5 minutes just parsing the first report. The script has a "break" statement in it and so it only works on 1st report but it is very slow.

```
import os
from lxml import html


def main():
    with open(os.getcwd()+'/dump.html', "r") as f:
        page = f.read()
    tree = html.fromstring(page)

    reportCount = len(tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"onereport")]'))

    sheet1, sheet2, sheet3=[], [], []
    for i in range(reportCount):
        print "Getting in "+str(i+1)+" report..."

        device     = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/table[1]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Device")]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0].split("> ")
        deviceID   = device[len(device)-1]

        timespan   = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/table[1]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Time Span")]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]
        uptime     = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/table[1]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Uptime Stats:")]/following-sibling::td[text()="Up:"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]
        uptimeDU   = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/table[1]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Uptime Stats:")]/following-sibling::td[text()="Up:"]/following-sibling::td/following-sibling::td/span/text()')[0]
        uptimeDo   = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/table[1]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Uptime Stats:")]/following-sibling::td[text()="Down:"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]
        uptimeDoDU = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/table[1]//tr/td[contains(text(), "Uptime Stats:")]/following-sibling::td[text()="Down:"]/following-sibling::td/following-sibling::td/span/text()')[0]
        pingTime   = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/table[2]//tr/td[text()="Ping Time"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]
        minimim    = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/table[2]//tr/td[text()="Minimum"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]
        maximum    = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/table[2]//tr/td[text()="Maximum"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]
        packetLoss = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/table[2]//tr/td[text()="Packet Loss"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]

        sheet1.append([deviceID, timespan, uptime, uptimeDU.replace("[", "").replace("]", ""), uptimeDo, uptimeDoDU.replace("[", "").replace("]", ""), pingTime, minimim, maximum, packetLoss])

        print "Getting in "+str(i+1)+" report's table1..."
        for j in range(len(tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/div[1]/form/table/thead[@class="headerswithlinks"]/following-sibling::tbody/tr'))):
            dateTime  = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/div[1]/form/table/thead[@class="headerswithlinks"]/following-sibling::tbody/tr['+str(j+1)+']/td/nobr/text()')[0]
            pTime     = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/div[1]/form/table/thead[@class="headerswithlinks"]/following-sibling::tbody/tr['+str(j+1)+']/td/text()')[0]
            mini      = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/div[1]/form/table/thead[@class="headerswithlinks"]/following-sibling::tbody/tr['+str(j+1)+']/td/text()')[1]
            maxi      = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/div[1]/form/table/thead[@class="headerswithlinks"]/following-sibling::tbody/tr['+str(j+1)+']/td/text()')[2]
            pLoss     = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/div[1]/form/table/thead[@class="headerswithlinks"]/following-sibling::tbody/tr['+str(j+1)+']/td/text()')[3]
            dTime     = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/div[1]/form/table/thead[@class="headerswithlinks"]/following-sibling::tbody/tr['+str(j+1)+']/td/text()')[4]
            coverage = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/div[1]/form/table/thead[@class="headerswithlinks"]/following-sibling::tbody/tr['+str(j+1)+']/td/text()')[5]

            sheet2.append([deviceID, dateTime, pTime, mini, maxi, pLoss, dTime, coverage])

        print "Getting in "+str(i+1)+" report's table2..."
        for k in range(len(tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr'))):
            status   = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr['+str(k+1)+']/td[1]/text()')[0]
            dtime    = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr['+str(k+1)+']/td[2]/nobr/text()')[0]
            duration = tree.xpath('//div[@class="onereport report'+str(i+1)+'"]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr['+str(k+1)+']/td[2]/nobr/span[2]/text()')[0]

            sheet3.append([deviceID, status, dtime, duration.replace("=", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "")])
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It takes 3 minutes on my sever with 1 core CPU and 1 GB ram, and on my own PC with 4 core CPU and 8 GB ram it takes 1.5 minutes. But the problem is if it will take 1+ minute for 1 report then it means that is at least 680 minutes for all the reports in html link i mentioned and that is like 11+ hours for just a 40mb html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Speeding up HTML parsing

One of the biggest problem the code has is that every single `.xpath()` call *traverses the complete HTML tree from the very root node*. This is very slow and you don't actually need to do that for every element.

**Make your searches context-specific** - loop over the "report" elements and look everything needed for this report directly inside the element - not from the root tree. Then, do similar things for the overview tables.

This is what [`lxml` docs are also noting about](http://lxml.de/performance.html#further-optimisations):

> A lot of time is usually spent in tree traversal to find the addressed
>   elements in the tree. If you often work in subtrees, do what you would
>   also do with deep Python objects: assign the parent of the subtree to
>   a variable or pass it into functions instead of starting at the root.
>   This allows accessing its descendants more directly.

Here is how I would go about the first part of parsing the report:

```
tree = html.parse('dump.html')

for index, report in enumerate(tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'onereport')]"), start=1):
    print("Getting in {index} report...".format(index=index))

    overview_table1, overview_table2 = report.xpath(".//table[@class = 'overview']")[:2]

    device_id = overview_table1.xpath('.//td[contains(., "Device")]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0].split("> ")[-1]

    timespan = overview_table1.xpath('.//td[contains(., "Time Span")]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]
    uptime = overview_table1.xpath('.//td[contains(., "Uptime Stats:")]/following-sibling::td[text()="Up:"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]

    uptime_stats = overview_table1.xpath('.//td[contains(., "Uptime Stats:")]')[0]
    uptime_du= uptime_stats.xpath('.//following-sibling::td[. = "Up:"]/following-sibling::td/following-sibling::td/span/text()')[0]
    uptime_do = uptime_stats.xpath('.//following-sibling::td[. = "Down:"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]

    uptime_do_du = uptime_stats.xpath('.//following-sibling::td[. = "Down:"]/following-sibling::td/following-sibling::td/span/text()')[0]

    ping_time = overview_table2.xpath('.//td[. = "Ping Time"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]
    minimim = overview_table2.xpath('.//td[. = "Minimum"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]
    maximum = overview_table2.xpath('.//td[. = "Maximum"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]
    packet_loss = overview_table2.xpath('.//td[. = "Packet Loss"]/following-sibling::td/text()')[0]

    print(device_id, timespan, uptime, uptime_do, uptime_du, uptime_do_du, ping_time, minimim, maximum, packet_loss)
    break
```

Apply the same improvement to other code blocks as well.

#### Other Thoughts

I also don't really like these "by text" searches. If the table structures are consistent, see if you can improve on searching the nodes based on the previous sibling texts - in other words, stop looking for a `td` by text and using `following-sibling`. Instead, get, say, all `tr` elements knowing which field is at which position. E.g. for the second overview table:

```
ping_time, minimim, maximum, packet_loss = overview_table2.xpath('.//tr/td[2]/text()')
```

Should also have a positive impact on performance.

Also, what if you would move from XPath locators all together - look into using [`cssselect`](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) or [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) (which would allow using `lxml` as an underlying parser).

Try [iterative parsing with `iterparse()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/324214/771848).

And, try the same code on *Python3.6*, if possible - it is generally a better, faster and more memory-efficient Python language implementation. You may get performance boosts "for free" just by upgrading your Python.

And, of course, *profile and know your bottlenecks!*

Comment: The modified version now takes only few minutes to parse everything, all thanks to you.

Comment: However you mentioned the use of bs4, is it more accurate because i have been working with lxml for a year now and the reason i chose it then was because it was fast and easier. Your thoughts?

Comment: `lxml` is faster than `bs4` indeed. It takes advantage of `xpath` instead of using regex based searches.